# Doesn't the Torah set the standard of politeness?

Tags: torah-reading, derech-eretz-manners, curse

Two of the curses in Ki Tavo are:

> -You shall betroth a wife, and another man will rape her. [Deut. 28:30]
>
> -The Lord will strike you with... hemorrhoids. [Deut. 28:27]

But the Talmud instructs us to read these lines differently than written:

> Our Rabbis taught in a baraita: All [biblical] verses written in an indelicate manner must be read by substituting refined phrasing.  [Examples:]
> -[Instead of reading] "You shall betroth a wife, and another man will rape her" [we read] "You shall betroth a wife, and another man will lie with her". [Deut. 28:30]
> -[Instead of reading] "The Lord will strike you with... hemorrhoids" [we read] "The Lord will strike you with... abscesses". [Deut. 28:27]
> [Megillah 25b]

Indeed, abscesses can occur anywhere in the body, but hemorrhoids only in the anus, so the first is more polite.  So, in the synagogue, the Torah reader must read the amended versions.

What I don't understand is this:  Doesn't the Torah DEFINE what is polite and what's not?  Should we not assume that if the Torah uses some words, they cannot be considered offensive?

**הֲפֹךְ בָּהּ וַהֲפֹךְ בָּהּ, דְּכֹלָּא בָהּ**
Turn it and turn it [the Torah], because everything is in it. [Avot 5:22]

Comment: I believe downvotes should not be allowed unless accompanied by an explanation.  I assume the purpose of this forum is to inform and provide feedback, not add and subtract points.

Comment: re your comment: see https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/144/170 & its answers

Comment: I don't understand why you think the Torah defines politeness. What does one have to do with the other?

Comment: Hafoch ba vehafoch ba, dekulla va.

Comment: In the first verse you bring, why do you translate the last word as 'will rape her'? It doesn't fit for [Jer. 3:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1103.htm#2), nor does it fit in the noun form, as used in [Pss. 45:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2645.htm#10) and [Neh. 2:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b02.htm#6), or in Aramaic in [Daniel 5:2-3, 23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3405.htm#2) . Also, [the Soncino translation of Megillah](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf) 25b (on p. 101 of the PDF) prefers to translate it as 'ravish'.

Comment: A better source for the Torah defining politeness might be [לעולם אל יוציא אדם דבר מגונה מפיו שהרי עקם הכתוב שמונה אותיות ולא הוציא דבר מגונה מפיו](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.3a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

Comment: @ba -- Doesn't this gemara just reinforce my point?  The Torah itself will tell us what is polite and what isn't.  "To avoid using the Hebrew term for impure [teme’a], which is four letters: Tet, mem, alef, heh, the [Torah] verse replaced the term with the euphemism meaning “that are not pure,” "

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi It does. That's the reason why I quoted it

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi, b a, actually it doesn't. The fact that in other places the Torah [_she-bi-Khtav_] is not opposed to using the "impolite" בהמה **טמאה** (in [Lev. 27:27](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0327.htm#27), and [Num. 18:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0418.htm#15)), means that you can't judge the politeness of a word simply by it's appearance in the Torah [_she-bi-Khtav_].

Comment: @TamirEvan I didn't write that it is a source for never using the word טמא. I wrote that it is a source for looking to the Torah for standards of politeness

Comment: @ba When Maurice Mizrahi commented "_[d]oesn't this gemara just reinforce my point_", I understood him to mean that he believed it reinforces the premise in his question, that a word (or phrase) used in the Written Torah is by definition polite. When you commented "_[i]t does_ ...", I understood you to agree with him that the _Gemara_ you quoted reinforces that premise in the question. That's why I directed my comment at you, as well as at him. If that's not what you meant, I apologize: I misunderstood you.

Comment: You should definitely replace "rape" because in Hebrew משגל is raw sex. So it'll be "another man will have sex with her" instead of "will lay with her". But the question is still good.